Prove that $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is generated by $−1$ and $5$.

Prove that $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is generated by $−1$ and $5$.

So, I am trying to understand this problem. What makes sense to me is that $\langle -1 \rangle$ will always generate $\{1, 2^n-1 \}$ and $\langle 5 \rangle$ should generate the rest, but I am struggling to see how it would work out in a couple of examples, specifically $(\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})^\times = \{1,3,5,7 \}$, but neither of my generators get to $3$.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

$3\equiv (-1)(5)\pmod 8$. You also need to take products of $-1$ and powers of $5$.

You can find this in Vinogradov, or other number theory texts.  It's well-known and I think due to Gauß.

It's not cyclic for $n\gt2,$ which is interesting.

Duplicate almost surely.

Yes, with the site search I found 3 duplicates within $\approx$ 5 minutes.
